# Cropping EUDEM with GDAL creates zig-zag terrain

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, terrain, europe

I have downloaded EUDEM (20 Gb) from http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/eu-dem#tab-original-data

When I try to crop it by GDAL using:

```
gdalwarp  -dstalpha -of EHdr -crop_to_cutline -cutline crop.shp eudem_dem_4258_europe.tif  eudem_cropped.flt
```

I get bad terrain. The terrain gets zig-zag in heights by 250 meters. Please check the screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

What do you think is the problem?

Comment: Can you upload the shapefile for testing purposes?